Uniform bound on norm of powers of invertible matrix
I am taking operator norm.Suppose A is an invertible matrix and $\|A\|>1$. Does it possible to find $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that$\|A^n\|<M$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$.               My approach: since most of the matrix I am calculating it is showing that norm is not uniformly bounded. I have tried by singular value decomposition to prove it but it’s not showing any results. Please help me in this problem. I don’t work in matrix theory just found this question trivially come in my mind.
Seriously I am trying this question whole day.
Edit; entries of matrix are coming from Real no or complex no.

Hint: play with nilpotent matrices, e.g. strictly upper triangular matrices, and see how large you can make the operator norm.

@TheoBendit Nilpotent matrices are never invertible.

I have mentioned that my matrix is invertible. For nilpotent matrix I will get uniform bound.

True, that's a problem with my suggestion, but I still think it's not a bad place to start. What if you made the eigenvalues very small instead?

Yes but other than normal matrix I have to think. If it’s normal matrix then norm of A^n will be n power of modules of biggest eigen value of A.

Here is an example:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & 1 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}$$
By a direct calculation, one can show that all entries of $A^n$ go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, so $\|A^n\| \to 0$.

Very good example. I didn’t knew about this idea to find counter example. I come with new question while working in this problem, i will ask you in this comment after trying on my own. Btw thank you so much.

@Tony You’re welcome. If you have a new question though, you should post a new question instead of asking in comments here.

My question was simple, is it possible to find example for same question but $0<||A^{-1}||<1$.

@Tony Ah, I suppose that’s reasonable to ask as a follow-up question in comments. The answer is no. The reason is that $A$ can have no eigenvalue of modulus strictly larger than $1$, as then $|A^n|$ will increase unboundedly. So $A$ must have all its eigenvalues with modulus smaller than or equal to $1$. But this will mean $A^{-1}$ has eigenvalues of modulus larger than or equal to $1$, so $|A^{-1}| \geq 1$.
